# LAMP installation

Tags: php, lamp, location

I would like to setup LAMP on my box,
I installed `apache2`,`mysql-server`,`php5`&`libapache`, restarted apache with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`, succesfully executed `php -r 'echo "\n\nYour PHP installation is working fine.\n\n\n";'` I now get the default **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page** when going to `http://127.0.0.1/` but where do my **php** files go? looks like php doesn't execute from within `/var/www/html/` and the browser can't find it in `/var/www/`. Where do I go with my php application?

Thanks!

Comment: It should go somewhere in /var/www/html/phpproject

Comment: They should go somewhere in `/var/www/html`. Did you install PHP for apache2 (`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`)?

Comment: @muru That was it, if you change your comment into an answer, I'll accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have Apache process PHP files, you need to install the PHP module for Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```